# How can I select the rows of an nd Tensor, with indexes stored in another Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to slice a Tensor of shape `(?, 32, 32)` along the first dimension. I have to select two rows with indexes stored in another Tensor of shape `(1, 2)`. I want something like `array[list of indexes, :, :]` in numpy.

How can I do it? I need this operation to compute a loss inside the `model_fn` function, passed to my custom Tensorflow Estimator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `tf.gather_nd`. I reshaped the tensor containing the indexes with:

`ids = tf.reshape(tensor_with_indexes, shape=(-1, 1))`

and then I applied:

`new_tensor = tf.gather_nd(original_tensor, ids)`